# Запуск сайта на node.js

Tags: node.js

Изучаю node.js и явно не понимаю какой-то очень важный элемент. Имеется пример из [книги](https://github.com/Swiftam/book-node-mongodb-backbone). А конкретно папка "ch05". В книге написано: "написать в командной строке `npm install`, чтобы установить зависимости" - сделал, все ОК. Затем нужно написать `node app.js`, в консоли пишется...

```
SocialNet is listening to port 8080
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что дальше делать? Хотелось бы увидеть страницу, на которой бы отработал код backbone.js. (запускаю из под windows, стоит iis).

Comment: Наберите в браузере `localhost:8080`, должно сработать. В хорошем сетапе у вас будет дополнительный сервер (nginx, например), который будет висеть на стандартном 80 порту, отдавать напрямую запросы на существующие файлы, а все несуществующие перенаправлять на этот порт, на котором висит нода. В IIS соответсвенно надо просто организовать прокси-сервер, который будет обращаться к этому порту 8080.  
Причем этот принцип более-менее одинаков и для руби, и для php, и для node.js.

Comment: Посмотрите скринкаст Ильи Бирмана.